# Update line graph based on table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a table with Max Min for each line graph. I want to build a macro that will update each line graph (40 in total) off of a table. Please Advise.

Here is what I have so far. I'm sure its poorly written as I'm starting to learn how to write VBA.

```
Sub Update_Slope()

    With Chart(2).Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("F58").Value
            ' Constant value
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("F68").Value
            ' Constant Value

    With Chart(4).Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("F59").Value
            ' Constant value
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("F69").Value
            ' Constant Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is Sub(update_slope) ? .. it should be Sub update_slope().

Comment: It says "sub or function not defined" referring to Chart. I wasn't sure if I was referring to the chart objects correctly.

Comment: @Sathish Kothandam it is still giving me the following error once I corrected that awful mistake "sub or function not defined"

Comment: @pnuts  I updated Charts -> Charts and am now getting run time error 9 - subscript out of range

Comment: Where are your charts?  On a worksheet? Which worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNTESTED

```
Sub Update_Slope()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart(2)").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Range("F68").Value
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Range("F58").Value

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart(4)").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Range("F69").Value
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Range("F59").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Update_All_Slopes()

    Dim co, sht as WorkSheet

    Set sht = Activesheet
    Set co = sht.ChartObjects

    'ideally you're looping through your table range to do this, instead
    '   of hard-coding each line. Need more info on how your sheet is set up
    '   and how to identify which chart should be updated...
    FixYAxis co("Chart2").Chart,sht.Range("F68").Value, sht.Range("F58").Value
    FixYAxis co("Chart4").Chart,sht.Range("F69").Value, sht.Range("F59").Value
    '...etc

End Sub

Sub FixYAxis(cht as Chart, minVal,maxVal)
    With cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = maxVal        
        .MinimumScale = minVal
    End With
End Sub
```